# bug nestjs/config when set config nestjs

Tags: nestjs

i create new project with `nest new new-project`
npm run start -> it run good
then i  install nest/config by `npm i -save @nest/config`

```
imports: ConfigModule.forRoot({
  envFilePath: '.development.env',
})
```

npm run start -> it show errorr:

> No valid exports main found for
>
> '/home/..../node_modules/@nestjs/config/node_modules/uuid'

error be this line

> config/dist/utils/create-config-factory.util.js:3:16

Answer (score 1):

[There are](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4833) [several closed](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4824) [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/724). It's an issue with your Node version, 13.6.0 has a problem with the UUID package, but 14 on doesn't.